# Unable to install Android SDK 17

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, android-sdk-2.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: trouble updating to Android SDK Tools, revision 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360894/android-trouble-updating-to-android-sdk-tools-revision-7)

I'm trying to install 6 new updates to the Android SDK (to version 17 from 16), I get this err msg:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

-= Warning ! =-
A folder failed to be moved. On Windows this typically means that a program is using that folder (for

examplle Windows Exploder or your anti-virus software.)
Please momentarily deactivate your anti-virus software or close any running programs that may be

accessing the directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-15'.
When ready, press YES to try again.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I closed everything except Eclipse itself, tried again; same err msg.

I then turned off MS Security Essentials; same err msg.

What need I do to get this install to "take"?

Update:

When I restart Eclipse, I get this err msg:

This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 17.0.0 or above.

Current version is 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534.

Please update ADT to the latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close Eclipse. Run the SDK Manager from your Android SDK directory instead of through Eclipse.

Comment: OK, I'll try that; I always run Eclipse as Administrator, though, so I didn't think that would be an issue.

Comment: It's because Eclipse is using the android sdk and locking the files.

Comment: Aha! So it's blaming the problem on someone else, when it's really causing the problem itself. Eclipse, or the SDK, is not far from becoming a human!