# "This verison of ADT requires Android SDK Tools in revision 17 or above." I can't get this error to go away.

Tags: android, mobile

The full text is:

```
This verison of ADT requires Android SDK Tools in revision 17 or above.
Current revision is 15.
Please update your SDK Tools to the latest version
```

When I get this error, it prompts me to open up the SDK Manager.

Then I select the newest version, and try to install it, but then I receive the error message:

```
-= Warning! =-
A folder failed to be moved. On Windows, this typically means 
that a program is using that folder...
```

So, I close Eclipse, and click 'Yes' to try again, but I keep getting the same error message.

Any idea on what to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install Android SDK 17](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823716/unable-to-install-android-sdk-17). Please do at least a basic search here before posting a new question; I found the linked answer with a search on `[android] SDK Tools Version 17` as the first result.

Comment: When I try to update it through Eclipse, I get this error I listed above:

    -= Warning! =-
    A folder failed to be moved. On Windows, this typically means 
    that a program is using that folder...

When I go directly through the ADK Manager, it tells me it's already installed ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/7wlQC.png))

I don't understand the disconnect between going directly through the ADK, and accessing it through Eclipse.

Comment: I followed the steps in the link you detailed, but it didn't work.  I even tried an additional set of steps detailed lower down in that link, but that didn't work either.  I'm thinking the best option is just to nuke everything and start again.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem on my mac by modifying the `plugin.prop` file:

for mac
    /Users/admin/Desktop/android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib/plugin.prop

for ubuntu 
    ......./android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/plugin.prop
Change the line from

```
plugin.version=17.0.0
```

to

```
plugin.version=16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
```

And reload eclipse.. and it no longer warns about anything.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run updates in the Android SDK on Windows, you need to run it as an Administrator. If you aren't an administrator, most upgrade operations will fail with permissions errors (they're not always reported as permissions errors, but that's what they are).

Right click on the SDK manager tool icon in your start menu, and select the "Run as Administrator" option.

You will then be able to run your upgrades.